# SQL Server date format to Datetimeoffset with specifc format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have database table that has datetime field in SQL Server.

I have to send as below sample.
Can you please help how to get this dateformat?

Example:  **2020-06-10T13:11:00-05:00**

Thanks

Comment: Support for `datetimeoffset` is minimal on SQL Server 2008, which is also completely unsupported. This would be trivial on fully supported version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you were on a supported version of SQL Server, this is actually quite trivial. If we *assume* the value in the table is `2020-06-10T13:11:00` it would just need a `CONVERT` and `SWITCHOFFSET`:

```
SELECT V.Dt,
       SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),V.dt),'-05:00')
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-06-10T13:11:00')))V(Dt);
```

If it's actually a UTC time, and you need to change it to (I assume) Central, then it would be:

```
SELECT V.Dt,
       CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),V.dt) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-06-10T18:11:00')))V(Dt);
```

Instead, you're going to have to do some `varchar` manipulation, as you're using a version  of SQL Server that is completely unsupported:

```
--If switching the offset
SELECT V.Dt,
       CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),CONVERT(varchar(20),V.Dt,126) + '-05:00')
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-06-10T13:11:00')))V(Dt);

--If changing the offset
SELECT V.Dt,
       CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEADD(HOUR, -5,V.Dt),126) + '-05:00')
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-06-10T18:11:00')))V(Dt);
```

Note that both of these are DST agnositic, as it `SWITCHOFFSET`. Only `AT TIME ZONE` will consider the DST.